# Как правильно подключить store в моем vue приложении?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli, vue3

Я только начал учить vue, пытаюсь сделать магазин на vue. С помощью vuex создал store, но никак не могу подключить его к моему проекту. При попытке подключить store в main.js выходить такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал разные статьи, возможно я путаю синтаксис vue2 и vue3, сам не знаю. Как мне правильно все подключить?

Мой store.js (store пока пустой)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл main.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

package.json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Vue 3 больше нету возможности глобальных установок Vue.* Теперь только пользуем instance и его аналогичные методы (.use, .component, .config, ...)

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const store = createStore({
  
});

export default store;
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import store from './vuex/store'

import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app')
```